# How to hide an element using Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I'm looking to permanently hide an element on this website I visit. I know this can be done with Greasemonkey, but I don't know how to do it.

**Here is the code:**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
<div class="widget-box">
<div class="widget-content">

<div id="40496">


<center>

<div class="alert alert-info">Coins: 4</div>

<span style="font-size:0.8em;" class="external-event ui-draggable label label-danger">Anti-Bots ne pas cliquer</span>
<img src="http://www.somesite.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/no_bots.jpeg" class="follower" width="150" height="112.5" border="0"><br><br>
```

What I need is to hide this entire element, but the reason it's hidden must be the `img src` or the "`Anti-Bots ne pas cliquer`" text. If I use any of the divs to hide it, or ID or anything else, it will hide content that I don't want hidden also. The img src or that text must be the association why the script will hide the element.

I hope I'm clear and that anyone can help.

Comment: What is 'this entire element'? The `span` and `img` are two separate elements, do you want to hide those two?

Comment: That first div  - <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3"> - expands into the rest of them. So I'd like to hide all of that, but the identifier must be either the span or the img.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding the `img` with a specific `src` can be done using an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) that is passed to [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to find all instances. We can then manually check if there is a `span` with the offending text somewhere in the `div`. The `div` can be found by considering the [`parentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement) until we find one with class `col-xs-12`.

Finally, everything must be executed only after the page has loaded. The result is as follows.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img[src="http://www.somesite.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/no_bots.jpeg"]');
  for (let img of imgs) {
    // find enclosing .col-xs-12
    let el = img;
    while (!el.classList.contains('col-xs-12')) {
      el = el.parentElement;
    }
    // find spans, check if one has the offending text
    let spans = el.querySelectorAll('span');
    for (let span of spans) {
      if (span.textContent === 'Anti-Bots ne pas cliquer') {
        el.parentElement.removeChild(el); // this deletes the div
        //el.style.display = 'none'; // this hides the div
        break;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<p>I should not be hidden.</p>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
<div class="widget-box">
<div class="widget-content">

<div id="40496">


<center>

<div class="alert alert-info">Coins: 4</div>

<span style="font-size:0.8em;" class="external-event ui-draggable label label-danger">Anti-Bots ne pas cliquer</span>
<img src="http://www.somesite.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/no_bots.jpeg" class="follower" width="150" height="112.5" border="0"><br><br>
```

Comment: You killed it man. Fantastic, works exactly as intended. Thanks a lot!